# Android ImageButton state not changing

Tags: android, selector, state, imagebutton

I have an issue with my ImageButton not changing state. When I click, or rather touch, the button it stays as the same image. Here is the XML I am using as a selector.

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
 android:state_focused="true"
 android:state_pressed="false"
 android:drawable="@drawable/pushed" />
<item
 android:state_focused="true"
 android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/pushed" />
<item
 android:state_focused="false"
 android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/pushed" />
<item  
 android:drawable="@drawable/default" />
</selector>
```

I call this selector from my main.xml as

```
android:background="@drawable/imagechoice"
```

imagechoice.xml is the file with the selector

I don't understand why this is not working, unless I have to have some java code, but everything I've seen said this should work.

Comment: Are you solve this problem? I have the same unresolved problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435660/imagebutton-selector-not-working

Answer (score 2):

When using an ImageButton, isn't it the 'src' property you should use and not background?

Comment: Well, the 'src' property puts a border around the image, and that also does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you copy the **same** images and the button XML into every "drawable" folders (hdpi,ldpi,mdpi).
That's how I solved this problem on my app.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I have nearly the same XML and it works just fine.  Are you sure you're not replacing the drawable in code somewhere?

On another note, your XML can be simplified by using the cascading nature of the state matching.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/pushed"
          />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/pushed"
          />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default"
          />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my xml of a button with my own custom image on it and it works great:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_off" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_off" />
</selector>
```

Comment: are you using an IDE such as Eclipse?  Maybe clean the project to make sure the R files refresh themselves and double check that the art is the correct art.  I'm not really sure why you're code isn't working.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, ill try to do that with the R files. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set Image button background as mentioned below.I think you are not setting the selector as background instead you are setting the image as background.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_up_selector"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#fffafa"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
```