# ImageButton selector not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to set selector for ImageView, but it is **not working**

My layout

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/orange_color"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/actions_top_bottom"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/actions_top_bottom"

        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/actions_height"
            android:id="@+id/btnNoRecord"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_record"
            android:onClick="onRecordSwitcherClick"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"/>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

My selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark_orange_color"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/orange_color"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Where is bug? Maybe there is something bug inside LinearLayout properties?

**EDIT**
I just found ImageButton outside LinearLayout working fine. But i'm really needed layout

Comment: the name is selector or Myselector.xml?

Comment: No. Name is selector.xml

Comment: Your selector is working on my device.What problem are you facing?

Comment: I do not see chenged background when i press button.

Comment: Do you want shadow?? @Sufferer

Comment: @Rani No, i do not want shadow - only background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it!

Inside my code i have

```
btnNoRecord.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
   {
       ...
       return true;
   }
});
```

I change **return true** to **return false** and it is working!

Answer (score 3):

put padding in your imageview to see the background selector

```
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/actions_height"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnNoRecord"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_record"
        android:onClick="onRecordSwitcherClick"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"/>

                         OR
```

Try it like this , this will work you have to give padding so that background selector is visible

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true">
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark_orange_color"/>
            <padding
            android:bottom="5dp"
            android:left="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:top="5dp" />
      </shape>
</item>
<item>
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <solid android:color="@color/orange_color"/>
          <padding
            android:bottom="5dp"
            android:left="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:top="5dp" />
      </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: forgot  </selector> in end file

Answer (score 3):

Set `clickable` attribute in your `ImageButton` as shown below:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/actions_height"
    android:id="@+id/btnNoRecord"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_record"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

`ImageButton` is extended from `ImageView`. The `clickable` attribute is false by default so you have to manually set it.

Comment: ImageButton is extended from ImageView,clickable attribute is false by default.

Comment: Dont foget add selector without selector not work !!!

Answer (score 2):

Your selector doesn't look correct.

I think you might be missing the states (ie. state_focused="true", etc).  It is important to remember that the selector is analyzed in order from top to bottom (so if a state is encountered first, the other items in the selector will be ignored - ie. order matters).

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_settings_inset_top_pressed"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_settings_inset_top_pressed"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_settings_inset_top"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_settings_inset_top"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I am not needed focused state. Also <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="true">...</item> not working too

Comment: This is a selector I use that for sure is functional. If you don't need all the particular states, you can omit the ones you don't need.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it, but it is not working. Are you tried your selector inside ImageButton  as property android:background?

Comment: Yes, I am using this exact code now by setting this selector as a background.  This is working in production.

Answer (score 0):

In this case just swap attributes:

```
android:src
android:background
```

to

```
android:src="@drawable/selector"
android:background="@drawable/ic_action_record"
```

Hint. You can remove background by:

```
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but this still needs some explanations.
There is a lot of such question on StackOverflow, but nobody really explains why this happened. Remember, Whenever you apply `ScaleType` to a view it's selector drawable will not be shown unless you gave some padding to it. What really happened, Is it takes out all the view width and height. And selector is really working, but src, drawable overlaps it. And it seems like it's not working. Especially happened in case of `FitXY`. Try some padding with it. And it will work. You can thank me later.